# TypeError: Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am making a react native app using expo for both iOS and android. I want to add firebase phone authentication to my app. I have followed the documentation provided by both expo and firebase but I am still getting the above error. I am getting one more error:

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Below is my code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig';

// Initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  //firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import PhoneAuth from './PhoneAuth';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>My Firebase App</Text>
      <PhoneAuth />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you expo project to be managed project. Have you added path of  google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist in your app.json file?